# See recorded activities on iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, healthkit

Is it possible to get the Activity app on an iPhone simulator?

Working on an Apple Watch workout app and it's a pain to keep building on my actual device in order to see the saved workouts, the simulator is a LOT faster but I can't seem to find anything about this.

It's not a programming related question so I'm sorry if this is not the correct place to ask.

Comment: No it's not possible you are only limited to the initial ones provided.  This is because the simulator does not provide the functionality needed by that app.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Aha that sucks, and how is that? If I run my app it simulates a workout just fine (HR, steps, distance), doesn't seem like it would be too difficult for Apple to provide the overview?

Comment: Sorry no idea you would have to ask Apple about that.

Answer (score 0):

Workouts performed in a Watch simulator will reflect in the Health app on the paired iPhone simulator.

To pair a Watch and iPhone simulator in Xcode 11:

1. Window > Devices and Simulators
2. Select Simulators tab
3. Tap '+' at the bottom left
4. Add an iPhone simulator and make sure the 'Paired Apple Watch' checkbox is checked
5. Add a Watch simulator

Start the Watch sim and record a workout.  Check the Health app on the paired iPhone simulator and you should see that your Watch workout was recorded.